# Xampp instancia y apache instancia

Tags: linux, apache, xampp

Tengo un servidor xampp con una web que hace referncia a un dominio (ejemplo: example.com).
Todo responde al puerto 80.
Despues tengo una aplicacion que levanta su propia instancia utilizando un apache interno donde para acceder se utiliza la ip publica, mas el puerto. En este caso es el 8123, solo se puede acceder ip:puerto.
La pregunta seria, como puedo configurar en xampp para que se pueda acceder a esa url (ip:puerto) utilizando el dns example.com/dynmap, sin afectar el funcionamiento de la url en el puerto 80?

Lamentablemente la aplicacion funciona asi, no puedo integrarla con xampp, por eso necesitaria tratar de alguna forma de poder enmascarla con xampp para que no muestre la ip.

Espero sus comentarios

Comment: Lo consigues con un [*Proxy*](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/es/howto/reverse_proxy.html) en el Apache de XAMPP.

Answer (score 0):

no-ip.com con eso configuras eso

https://www.noip.com/es-MX/sign-up?gclid=Cj0KCQiA54KfBhCKARIsAJzSrdqwX-HfW6EvMCpOs-r0OeG-5Rz6c3kjF7gjfRNYwmSfYUK-Dc_T9qYaAor4EALw_wcB&utm_campaign=free-dynamic-dns&utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=google

sin enbargo tu pregunta no refiere a programacion o codigo fuente